# How to move local git repository to new remote repo with some history

Tags: git

I am unable to access the git server due to server issues. So I am trying to move my existing local github repo to a new gitlab repo.

As of now I did below steps from my local repo

```
git remote set-url origin new-gitlab-url
git push -uf origin main
```

But got fatal error for a very old commit: did not receive expected object.
I tried different ways to resolve the issue but nothing worked.
Is there a way to create a new repo with certain history i.e from given old commit to latest commit? So that, atleast from the commit just after the commit with issues can be copied to new repo

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is in general the correct process. Can you update your question to show the exact error message?

Comment: What do you mean by "local github repo"?  Do you just mean a git repository that has a github url as one of its remotes, or do you mean something else?  It seems a very odd expression.